# Proper data structure for Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I am currently working on a IOS app with the backend being supplied by Firebase. It's my first time working with a `NOSql`backend and wanted some input on how best to structure my data. Currently the app is going to be a user based app that has only details related to each user appearing in their feed. So if they post a note to the notes area, only they will have access to it. There will be no sharing of this information. How I have my data currently setup is to have an endpoint called "notes" and an endpoint called "users". I planned on putting everyones notes in "notes" and then having an entry under each user of "notes" with a reference to the "noteId" in the main "notes" area. Does this make more sense then just having a child of "users" being "notes" with the actual note data there?

```
notes >
    noteId >
        noteName
        noteDetails
    noteId >
        noteName
        noteDetails
    noteId >
        noteName
        noteDetails

user >
    notes >
         noteId
         noteId
         noteId (these would reference the note in notes)
    name 
    dateAdded
```

This is somewhat how the data looks currently. Is this the best approach. I have a mySql background and am having troubles fully understanding noSql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keeping the notes for all users in a single top-level node makes sense if you ever need to access notes across users. But note that you should be *very* careful **querying** across all notes, as that is likely going to become a bottle neck if your app becomes really successful.

If you only ever need to access notes for a specific user, you might as well partition the notes for each user separately:

```
notes >
  user1 >
    noteId >
        noteName
        noteDetails
    noteId >
        noteName
        noteDetails
  user2 >
    noteId >
        noteName
        noteDetails
```

This data structure leads to better isolation of data, at the cost of not having a long list of notes.

Aside from that, you're nesting data that should be flattened: user profiles and user notes, should be in separate top-level nodes:

```
users >
    userId >
         name 
         dateAdded
userNotes >
    userId >
         noteId
         noteId
         noteId (these would reference the note in notes)
```

With this you can retrieve a list of user names, without also getting all their note IDs. Then when you need to show the notes for a specific user, you just access their note keys under `/userNotes/<uid>` and then load each node.

If you're new to NoSQL data modeling, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/). If you come from a relational/SQL background, I recommend viewing [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: Awesome. that totally all makes sense. I have been having a hard time with the flattened data approach after years of php and relational databases. Thanks so much.

Comment: You're not alone in that. :-) It mostly takes some "unlearning" and then logical thinking (without constantly comparing to SQL). I added some links for reading/viewing.